# "Let it will be"

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis, subjunctive-mood

"Let it be" is an easy phrase to understand and to use. It's widely used and it's a set phrase, so it's hard to make mistake here.

Why would a native speaker say "Let it will be"? Is it the same "let it be" phrase with a mistake? At first I thought it was a mistake because the verb LET requires object + infinitive without "to".

Or was it said so on purpose to mean something else?

Comment: It doesn't sound like anythimg a native speaker should say.

Comment: Are you claiming to have heard this? Is 'Let it will be' the sum total of what the speaker said?

Comment: I would suggest either eggcorn, or perhaps misheard.

Comment: I know it's a song title. And it sounds really like "Let it will be" in the song. I know in rap songs I can find any kind of grammar perversion, but this one is by Madonna (who seems ok with speech).

Comment: @ChrisinAK , could you explain what eggcorn stands for, or share a link where it's best explained?

Comment: @PabloDescamisado Google eggcorn www.google.com/search?q=eggcorn.

Comment: One could *contrive* a valid context, such as a somewhat "affected" speaker saying *"I'm moving in with my fiance after Christmas, but I don't want to **sell** my house in case it doesn't work out. So **let it will be**"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers That sentence still doesn't parse for me. What is the affected speaker trying to say?

Comment: @DanBron "To let" = "to rent out." _I don't want to sell my house, so **rent** it will be_ (rather than _sell_).

Comment: @justin Ah, thanks! That totally threw me (where I'm from, we rarely hear and never use *let* in that sense).

Comment: @DanBron No problem. I'm in the same boat (western US), we don't use "to let" like that at all, but thanks to a study abroad in Wales, a few Britishisms have stuck in my head; I'm glad to put that information to good use!

Comment: @Pablo Simply because no one has said it explicitly yet: "*Let it will be*" is ***not*** a song title, nor the lyrics of a song. At least no well-known nor popular song.

Comment: @Justin Greer: Close enough! :) I meant it as a "past tense" usage though. Indistinguishable in writing *or* speech until you change the verb - *"so **rented** it will be"* (equivalent to *"let it be **rented** out"*).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is (probably) based on a misapprehension. If it really is a song title, it is still off-topic, because lyrics and poetry are affected by things other than simple grammar.

Comment: I know everything about simple grammar. I'm not learning. Of course if I asked "is this phrase with a mistake", I'll get the response "yes, it is. the correct one is LET IT BE". Here I wanted to find out if this very line was containing some difficult grammar which doesn't appear obvious.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so more of an adjectival usage, then, sort of. That's fascinating! I'm glad I got your meaning well enough anyway. Now if I can just find a way to work your contrived sentence into casual speech...

Comment: @Justin: If you're determined to use the construction, I suppose I'll have to accept that ***used it will be***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the Madonna song "[Let It Will Be](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfoZyqddOhU)".

First off, songs are not a reliable source for grammatically accurate English.  You won't find a native speaker that thinks "let it will be" is good grammar.

Most likely, Madonna is using "let it will be" as a corruption of "let it be."  The refrain:

```
 That it will be
 Just let it be
 Oh let it be
 Then it will be
```

is part of the chorus.  "That it will be" is valid English, just as "oh let it be."  I'm assuming "Let it will be" is an attempt at wordplay to bridge the gap between these phrases.

Comment: It is rather curious that *Let it will be* only occurs at the title of Madonna's song, and not in its lyrics (which your YouTube link also points to).

Comment: @ErikKowal I think some of the "that it will be"s are actually "let it will be", especially during the call and response sections.  (The lyrics with the Youtube video aren't super accurate).  However, other lyric sites show only "let it will be"s (instead of that/then it will be), and I don't think that's correct either.

Comment: I've just listened to the song all the way through while reading the lyrics. As far as I could make out, there is one instance of 'let it will be' from the backing singers in the antepenultimate verse (though this isn't reflected in the lyrics as reproduced on the page). It's altogether quite strange.